# To set auto restart of a service with a user other than root

Tags: init.d

I want the service to auto restart on reboot of system. It's already placed in init.d file, but am not getting what can be modified to get it restarted by some other group of users?

Comment: systemd upstart or sysvinit?  `ps -p 1 -o comm=`

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is accomplished with:

```
chkconfig <service> on
```

on CentOS/Fedora/RHEL

and with:

```
update-rc.d <service> defaults
```

on Ubuntu/debian.

Both commands need to be run as root